# Can't find menu id?

Tags: android

I've stumbled upon an issue that i didn't have before,must've deleted something and messed it up but i really can't figure out where..
I'm doing a menu on the action bar but after i add the items on the main.xml file from the menu folder and setting them id's,it can't find the id's in my activities.What's the issue ? I tried cleaning and other stuff but i can't figure this out...

Here's my onCreateOptionsMenu :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.setari:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        finish();
        break;

    case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        finish();
        break;




    }
    return false;
}
```

And here's my main.xml inside the menu folder :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/setari"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

 <item android:id="@+id/admprod"
       android:title="Administrare produse" android:orderInCategory="1"/>

 <item android:id="@+id/despre"
       android:title="Despre" android:orderInCategory="3"/>

  <item android:id="@+id/iesire"
       android:title="Iesire" android:orderInCategory="4"/>
```

Some things might not have a logic,that's because i tried a lot of stuff to fix this..

Comment: Try `R.id.setari` `android.R` is reserved for preset widgets.

Comment: Oh,yea..that was it,damn,lol..thanks ! I knew it was something pretty stupid,heh.Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

If the error is showing for every menu id, then probably you have imported the `android.R` instead of your `package.R` .

Make sure that you have imported the `R` class of your project, not the `android.R` class.

Comment: Isn't the correct R auto-imported, even if android.R is also imported?

Comment: That's not what I'm contesting. When you say "make sure that you have imported the `R` class of your project," it's misleading because, as far as I know, that's not something you can do manually.

Comment: you can import using ctrl+shift+o... may be i am still not clear about your point.. but you can definitely import R manually

Comment: I've seen `android.R` imported at the top of Eclipse files, but never have I seen `package.R` imported anywhere

Comment: ok .. may be you are not clear about my point... you have to import your package's R file ... like import com.example.test.R; ... if you are not familiar with this .. then I think you better study a bit more.